# Loop is more important than rest?

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to execute simple code when user click on my button:

1. First: change my cursor to 'wait'
2. Next: execute loop
3. When loop is finished: change cursor back to 'default'

I wrote this code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="gogogo">Go!</button>

<div id="progress">0</div>
```

JS:

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

document.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = (function(){
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

  for(var ii = 0; ii < 30000; ii += 1){
    progress.textContent = ii;
  }

  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';

});
```

Live code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Bz27/2/

And something is wrong. Loop execute first, and after that happen cursor changing.
Is it possible or any way related to asynchronous?

Comment: Cursor doesn't change at all for me in Chrome. The function could be working correctly but too quickly to see.

Comment: put an alert after the cursor = 'wait' and see what has been done.

Comment: @Virus721 and I still don't uderstand. Why that's happen ?

Comment: the for loop blocks the system, as it's not async. anyway it's so fast thats impercettible. if you want to create some sort of animation you can use javascript:(transitionend event, request animationframe,settimeout which are time based or ajax,filreader,websql,indexeddb which are async)

Comment: @cocco Yes, it's definitely block everything but why code before it ? For now loop fire first and then previous code

Comment: and the worst option is setTimeout

Comment: what you wanna achieve? numbers in progress ?? timebased? animations?? load something?

Comment: maybe it executes the loop first because chrome sets the cursor in some sort of async way and so your loop starts before it loads the cursor correctly.

Comment: if the case is what i just wrote.. you can simply wait 50ms(after u set the cursor) so the browser has all the time to set the proper cursor... but if your functions lasts so long in the code is something wrong.and if it does not work try 1000ms

Comment: it's like/similar the problem on images ... if you put the onload after src sometimes the image loads so fast that the browser can't execute the onload event.

Comment: @cocco It's not chrome problem. Firefox react the same. This counter is for array. I load thousands links to the JS array and then manipulate them. For the UX reasons I want show progress of operations to user. So I want show for example cursor wait, and when operations are finished change back it to default. But AbdylSy post show me the way. But your advices also were helpful, so thanks ;)

Comment: @PiotrWójcik Nice question, thanks. +1 User `Cocco` has some very good points in his answer and comments. No idea why anyone would have down-voted his answer, it's excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a blocking operation.  This will certainly cause slow script warnings at some point.   You can solve this by making the loop asynchronous:

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

document.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = (function(){
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

    var index = 0,
        updater;

    updater = function() {
        progress.textContent = index++;

        if (index < 30000) {
            setTimeout(updater, 50);
        } else {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';           
        }
    };

    updater();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your styles are applied only after the call stack has finished. You can separate this into two different call stacks by running the second half of the function from a setInterval like this:

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

document.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = (function(){
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

    setTimeout(function(){

        for(var ii = 0; ii < 30000; ii += 1){
            progress.textContent = ii;
        }

        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }, 0);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

RequestAnimationFrame Way

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTBXN/)

```
(function (W) {
    W.onload = function () {
        var D = W.document,
            a = 0,
            c = D.getElementById('progress');

        function b() {
            c.innerText = a + 1;
            a++;
            if (a < 500) {
                requestAnimationFrame(b);
            } else {
                D.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }

        function start() {
            D.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            b()
        }
        D.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = start;
    }
})(window)
```

This way you use less resources and so your complex link modification does not slow down other open websites.

Comment: In your experience, why is RequestAnimationFrame method better than SetTimeout ?

Comment: Your method sounds interesting, but code posted above is difficult for me to follow. Also, the above code doesn't seem to work with the jsFiddle posted by the OP. Would you mind creating a jsFiddle with your code?

Comment: requestanimationframe executes slower than settimeout and adds the posibility to create nice animation while you execute long code and like i said when u load thousends of links the browser could get instable... it also could create some strange memory leaks if used wrong. requestanimationframe is made exactly for that.

Comment: what you don't understand?-- i'm not registered at jsfiddle

Comment: the ()() closures at the begining and at the end are to put this code in every site even if it has different libraries, and they also execute the function inside directly. i had to put a onload esle you can't get the getElementById elements, using var a,b,c,d is better than writing tons of var and so you also cache the elements .. if you call getElementById inside a loop it has every time to search this element.caching window and document is also a good solution especially if you don't want to write thousend times document.i prefer bitwise operators over math and shorthand if because faster -1

Answer (score 1):

Your Loop is happening too fast for any result to be shown.

Everything is done but in about < 1ms.
You could use timeouts to delay what's being shown so that you can see what's happening.

**Edit**: here is the JsFiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Bz27/9/

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

var restoreCursor= function () {
   document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
 }

document.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = (function(){
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

    var ii = 0;
    // this is a immediately executed function
    //that calls itself with a small timeout  
    (function goLoop(){

        progress.textContent = ii;

        if(ii<30000){
           ii++;
           setTimeout(goLoop,10);
        }else {
          restoreCursor();
        }

    })();



});
```

replace your jsFiddle by that and you're good to go.

personnally for better performance i would iterate over each frame.
like this:

```
var ii =0;
(function goLoop(){
  progress.textContent = ii;
  if(ii>3000) {
    ii++;
    requestAnimationFrame(goLoop);
})();
```

Comment: This will just set the cursor back to 'default' immediately.  You need to set this when you reach 30000

Comment: Won't this infinite loop?

Comment: @sp00m and
craig Nope that won't because there's a slight timeout between each call; the function calls itself only if the value of ii is less that the value provided.
I'll post a jsFiddle to play with.

Comment: You still set the cursor back to default straight away.  You need to set the cursor to default within the async function when it reaches its target of 30000

Comment: Ok based on @AbdoulSy code I wrote this:
    var ii =0;
    document.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = (function(){

        function goLoop(){
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
          progress.textContent = ii;
          if(ii<300) {
            ii++;
            requestAnimationFrame(goLoop);
          }else{
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          }
        };
        goLoop();
    })

And it works. Thanks :D

Comment: @craig oh yeah thanks, you're right I was more focused on the loop thing as it was the issue;
By adding a restoreCursor function in the loop you'll get to the desired behaviour. -> made the edit

Comment: This has nothing to do with the speed at which the loop executes, and the timeouts don't make it work because they "slow it down". JavaScript is single-threaded, the loop offers no opportunity for the browser to redraw itself.

Comment: @maegar Having worked with operations on 100000+ rows, if you don't perform rendering operations in `setTimeout` calls, you will inevitably get slow script warnings.  It's a known issue that performing `setTimeout`s is slower, but it's a trade-off between that or the browser hanging while it operates and then prompting the user to "Stop slow scripts or continue".

Comment: @maegar, Sorry, bad choices of words, but as Craig said, we could add a timeout to the loop to make it inside an other js execution and make the loop huge, and that could resolve his issue, but from what is expected by the Author's question, is more a way to show a number incrementally and if you have a better solution that recursive timeouts or requestAnimationFrame I would be honored to know your solution.

Comment: @Craig I never said otherwise? I have no problem with using `setTimeout`, it's the solution I would choose. As I said, it's necessary to release the single thread of execution so the browser can redraw itself.