# Mouse cursor only changed when over specific element

Tags: javascript

In this code, taken from [Cocco's answer/jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTBXN/) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339077/loop-is-more-important-than-rest#18339938), the mouse cursor is only changed to "wait" style when the mouse is hovering over the `progress` div.

Why is that, and how to make it so that the cursor is the wait style all over that page, until the operation is completed?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="gogogo">Go!</button>
<div id="progress">0</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function (W) {
    W.onload = function () {
        var D = W.document,
            a = 0,
            c = D.getElementById('progress');

        function b() {
            c.innerText = a + 1;
            a++;
            if (a < 3000) {
                requestAnimationFrame(b);
            } else {
                D.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }

        function start() {
            D.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            b()
        }
        D.getElementById('gogogo').onclick = start;
    }
})(window)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because your body is only about 40px tall. Add:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

to take up the height of the browser.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DTBXN/3/)**

Comment: Instead of hiding overflow, get rid of margin & padding